# cssTrnsitionGroup with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I need help:
How can I pass a `className` to `cssTransition` with `styled-components`, Given this example code:

```
<CSSTransition timeout={timeout} classNames={classNames}>
  {children}
</CSSTransition>
```

className in CSSTransition something like this:

```
* classNames={{
*   appear: '.my-appear',
*   appearActive: '.my-appear-active',
*   appearDone: '.my-appear-done',
*   enter: '.my-enter',
*   enterActive: '.my-enter-active',
*   enterDone: '.my-enter-done',
*   exit: '.my-exit',
*   exitActive: '.my-exit-active',
*   exitDone: '.my-exit-done'
* 
*}}

{
  timeout: TransitionTimeouts.slow,
  classNames: {
    enter: rightTransitionEnter,
    exit: rightTransitionExit,
  },
}
```

how to pass selectors by `className` with **rightTransitionEnter** and **rightTransitionExit** Styled Components with my example code?
Sorry for my bad english.